# Rails: Find rows without connection in HABTM relation

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, has-and-belongs-to-many

I have two models, `Users` and `Leads` connected with HABTM relation:

```
class Lead < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_and_belongs_to_many :users
end

class User < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_and_belongs_to_many :leads
end
```

How can I now get only those Leads which are not connected to Users?

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 10, accepted):

What you're looking for is known as an **[anti join](http://blog.montmere.com/2010/12/08/the-anti-join-all-values-from-table1-where-not-in-table2/)** .

There are three standard ways to accomplish this,

1. Using a null left outer join
2. Using a where clause with a sub query with the `NOT` & `IN` keywords
3. Using a where clause with the `NOT` & `EXISTS` keywords

Basically, the `EXISTS` keyword will check if any row is returned by the sub query and report that as a match, `NOT` obviously negates that true match.

here's my preferred way (using `NOT` & `EXISTS`)

```
class User < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_and_belongs_to_many :leads
  def self.without_leads
    where(<<-SQL)
      NOT EXISTS (SELECT 1 
        FROM   leads_users 
        WHERE  users.id = leads_users.user_id) 
    SQL
  end
end

class Lead < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_and_belongs_to_many :users
  def self.without_users
    where(<<-SQL)
      NOT EXISTS (SELECT 1 
        FROM   leads_users 
        WHERE  leads.id = leads_users.lead_id) 
    SQL
  end

 def self.not_connected_to(user)
    where(<<-SQL, user.id)
      NOT EXISTS (SELECT 1 
        FROM   leads_users 
        WHERE  leads.id = leads_users.lead_id
        AND leads_users.user_id = ?
        ) 
    SQL
  end
end
```

here's a **non SQL** approach using arel

```
class User < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_and_belongs_to_many :leads
  def self.without_leads
    habtm_table = Arel::Table.new(:leads_users)
    join_table_with_condition = habtm_table.project(habtm_table[:user_id])
    where(User.arel_table[:id].not_in(join_table_with_condition))
  end
end

class Lead < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_and_belongs_to_many :users
  def self.without_users
    habtm_table = Arel::Table.new(:leads_users)
    join_table_with_condition = habtm_table.project(habtm_table[:lead_id])
    where(Lead.arel_table[:id].not_in(join_table_with_condition))
  end
end
```

[here is an example repo](https://github.com/mikfreedman/habtm-not-exists-example)

Find users without leads

```
User.where(user_id: 1).without_leads
```

Find leads without users

```
Lead.without_users
```

Find leads not connected to a specific user

```
Lead.not_connected_to(user)
```

chain a sort

```
Lead.without_users.order(:created_at)
```

Comment: Wow, your answer looks great! Could you only advice me how to sort leads based on current_user id? I want to display leads that have not been bought by current user only, others still need to see it. How about moving it to Lead model instead of User? Is it good idea?

Comment: Hmm now I do not get any results. Query from console looks like this: `SELECT COUNT(*) FROM `users` WHERE `users`.`id` = 1 AND (`users`.`id` NOT IN (SELECT `leads_users`.`user_id` FROM `leads_users` ))`

Comment: @fizzlebubble i'll update the answwer to do it from the leads side. my  current answer will show you users without leads

Comment: @fizzlebubble see my example `Lead.without_leads` method for your exact problem, leads not connected to a specific user

Comment: Thanks for your effort! We are nearly solution! Leads get filtered nicely but you might got me wrong. For example, we have two users (User_A and User_B). When User_A buy a lead he should not see it on list anymore, but User_B still should see it. I am using devise gem so how about passing id to model's method? If it is good approach how can I make it? :-)

Comment: you should use [CanCan](https://github.com/ryanb/cancan) along with devise. Devise provides **authentication** but not **authorization**

Comment: I am using Devise and CanCan.

Comment: I'm pretty sure if you did this, `Lead.not_connected_to(User_B)` he will see a lead that has been assigned to User_A, but not to himself.

Comment: It shows all leads. Query looks like this: `SELECT COUNT(*) FROM `leads` WHERE ( NOT EXISTS (SELECT 1
 FROM leads_users
 WHERE leads.id = leads_users.lead_id
 AND leads_users.user_id <> 1
 )
)`

Comment: But as I login on other user I see that it works and I do not lead that has been bought, but it should works other way, user which bought do not see his lead but other users does :P.

Comment: fixed solution, should've been `= ?` instead of `<> ?` in the `Lead.not_connected_to` method

Comment: Mate you are great! I am veeeeery thankful for your time and effort! Could you explain me what `<>` in SQL means?

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/48552/discussion-between-mikfreedman-and-fizzlebubble)

Comment: it's sad i can't upvote this question more than once, thanks a lot!

Comment: Do you know an Arel approach to `Lead.not_connected_to(user)` as well?

Answer (score 3):

You can use a left join. Assuming your join table is named `leads_users`:

```
Lead.joins('LEFT JOIN leads_users ON leads_users.lead_id = leads.id').
     where(leads_users: { user_id: nil })
```

Comment: The cross reference table should be leads_users. For simplicity (and less DB type dependence) the where clause could be leads_users: {user_id: nil}

Comment: You're right @Coenwulf and I'm going to edit the answer accordingly. Thanks.

Comment: Your solution works, but I still have a little problem. I want to display leads that have not been bought by current user only, others still need to see it. I was trying to change `user_id: nil` to `"user_id =! #{current_user.id}"` but it throws error like this `syntax error, unexpected '}', expecting tASSOC`. Full code looks like this: `Lead.joins('LEFT JOIN leads_users ON leads_users.lead_id = leads.id').where(leads_users: { "user_id =! #{current_user.id}" })`

Answer (score 0):

Kerozu, you can use raw sql like this

```rb
    sql = <<-SQL
      SELECT *
      FROM leads
      WHERE id NOT IN (
        SELECT lead_id
        FROM leads_users
        WHERE user_id = ?
      )
    SQL

    Lead.find_by_sql [sql, id]
```

Answer (score 0):

Simpler rails NOT IN

```
Lead.all.where.not(id: Lead.all.joins(:users))
```