# Rails: Finding HABTM records that do (or do not) have an association

Tags: ruby-on-rails-4, has-and-belongs-to-many

I am trying to find a more efficient way to do the following:

I have two models in a HABTM relationship and I would like to find all the records in one model that are not associated with the other model. The only way I've come up with so far is:

```
m2_list = []
ModelOne.all.each do |m1|
  if m1.model_twos.empty?
    m2_list << m1
  end
end
```

Would be really nice is there was a single query that could return `m2_list` directly. Is there such a beast?

Comment: I think the answers in this post may help you: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22053918/rails-find-rows-without-connection-in-habtm-relation (I would opt for the AREL solution)

Comment: Wow! What a difference! Execution time of 3 seconds as opposed to 71 before! Thanks, @edwardmp!

I don't understand all the mumbo-jumbo yet but I'm happy to use it. :)